# How to have pytest2 and pytest3 cohabit next to each other?

Tags: python, pytest

Installing `pytest` using `pip` or `pip3` will install `pytest` for Python2 and `pytest` for Python3 respectively. But both are to be invoked by typing the same command `pytest`… Which means that only one of the two can be used at once!! (That is, the one that has been installed latest)

It seems the `pytest` binary

```
~/.local/bin/pytest
```

is bound either one of

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest.py
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest.py
```

which cannot be accessed directly.

How to have a `pytest2` and `pytest3` command?

Comment: Do you know about [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) and/or [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)?

Answer (score 2):

In linux you can use alias

for example:

```
alias search=grep
```

now you can use search as alias of grep

in your case:

```
alias pytest2="python ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest.py"
alias pytest3="python3 ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest.py"
```

To make the alias permanent than you should save them in your bashrc file:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting idea I had not thought of! Although your proposal seems to have some robustness issues as well (reliance on a specific Python version: 2.7 and 3.6)

Comment: Also a small technical detail: an issue with aliasses which I have just come accross implementing your solution, is that [bash scripts don't seem to recognize them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases)… And Makefiles as well, hence my `make test` won't longer work… (Obvious workaround: create `pytest2` and `pytest3` shell scripts that run the commands you suggested above)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple workaround I have found, eventhough I am not 100% confident it will be very maintainable in the future, especially in tems of robustness to python or system package updates:

The `~/.local/bin/pytest` file is a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pytest import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

As can be seen, what makes it call the pytest for Python3 is the first line `#!/usr/bin/python3`. Changing the python version in this line to `python2` would make it call pytest for Python2 instead.

Hence one could make two copies of this file:

- `~/.local/bin/pytest3` that is identical to the original (shown above)
- `~/.local/bin/pytest2` where the first line was changed to `#!/usr/bin/python2`

Comment: oh, nice! I didn't know the content of pytest. Seems a good workaround